# Replace with minimum value within group

Tags: dplyr, tidyverse

The groups in V4 always have 2 rows.

1. I would like to replace the values in V7 with the minimum values in V7 of the two rows.
2. I would like to replace the values in V8 with the maximum values in V8 of the two rows.

Btw: the df is ordered in ascending order by V7

df:

```
   # A tibble: 6 × 12
# Groups:   V4 [3]
  V1           V2        V3 V4       V5 V6           V7        V8    V9   V10 V11   V12  
  <chr>     <int>     <int> <chr> <int> <chr>     <int>     <int> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
1 chr9  130714314 130714460 ABL1      0 .     130714314 130714460     0     1 146,  0,   
2 chr9  130883963 130885688 ABL1      0 .     130883963 130885688     0     1 1725, 0,   
3 chr1  179107712 179109446 ABL2      0 .     179107712 179109446     0     1 1734, 0,   
4 chr1  179229235 179229402 ABL2      0 .     179229235 179229402     0     1 167,  0,   
5 chr2  157737525 157737670 ACVR1     0 .     157737525 157737670     0     1 145,  0,   
6 chr2  157799421 157799498 ACVR1     0 .     157799421 157799498     0     1 77,   0,
```

put

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("chr9", "chr9", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", 
"chr2"), V2 = c(130714314L, 130883963L, 179107712L, 179229235L, 
157737525L, 157799421L), V3 = c(130714460L, 130885688L, 179109446L, 
179229402L, 157737670L, 157799498L), V4 = c("ABL1", "ABL1", "ABL2", 
"ABL2", "ACVR1", "ACVR1"), V5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V6 = c(".", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "."), V7 = c(130714314L, 130883963L, 179107712L, 
179229235L, 157737525L, 157799421L), V8 = c(130714460L, 130885688L, 
179109446L, 179229402L, 157737670L, 157799498L), V9 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V10 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V11 = c("146,", 
"1725,", "1734,", "167,", "145,", "77,"), V12 = c("0,", "0,", 
"0,", "0,", "0,", "0,")), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    V4 = c("ABL1", "ABL2", "ACVR1"), .rows = structure(list(1:2, 
        3:4, 5:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Out:

```
   # A tibble: 6 × 12
# Groups:   V4 [3]
  V1           V2        V3 V4       V5 V6           V7        V8    V9   V10 V11   V12  
  <chr>     <int>     <int> <chr> <int> <chr>     <int>     <int> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
1 chr9  130714314 130714460 ABL1      0 .     130714314 130885688     0     1 146,  0,   
2 chr9  130883963 130885688 ABL1      0 .     130714314 130885688     0     1 1725, 0,   
3 chr1  179107712 179109446 ABL2      0 .     179107712 179229402     0     1 1734, 0,   
4 chr1  179229235 179229402 ABL2      0 .     179107712 179229402     0     1 167,  0,   
5 chr2  157737525 157737670 ACVR1     0 .     157737525 157799498     0     1 145,  0,   
6 chr2  157799421 157799498 ACVR1     0 .     157737525 157799498     0     1 77,   0,
```

I tried this, which gives me the minimum values, but not sure how to get the max in V8:

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(V4) %>%
  dplyr::slice(which.min(V7))
```

Maybe this works?

```
lag(x, n = 1L, default = NA, order_by = NULL, ...)

lead(x, n = 1L, default = NA, order_by = NULL, ...)
```

Comment: df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(V4) %>%
  mutate(min=min(V7)) %>%
  mutate(end=max(V8))

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("chr9", "chr9", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2"), 
                     V2 = c(130714314L, 130883963L, 179107712L, 179229235L, 157737525L, 157799421L), 
                     V3 = c(130714460L, 130885688L, 179109446L, 179229402L, 157737670L, 157799498L), 
                     V4 = c("ABL1", "ABL1", "ABL2", "ABL2", "ACVR1", "ACVR1"), 
                     V5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                     V6 = c(".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."), 
                     V7 = c(130714314L, 130883963L, 179107712L, 179229235L, 157737525L, 157799421L), 
                     V8 = c(130714460L, 130885688L, 179109446L, 179229402L, 157737670L, 157799498L), 
                     V9 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                     V10 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                     V11 = c("146,", "1725,", "1734,", "167,", "145,", "77,"), 
                     V12 = c("0,", "0,", "0,", "0,", "0,", "0,")), 
                class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
                groups = structure(list(V4 = c("ABL1", "ABL2", "ACVR1"), 
                                        .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6), 
                                                          ptype = integer(0), 
                                                          class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), 
                                   class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                                   row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
                                   .drop = TRUE))


cleaned_df <- df %>% 
  group_by(V4) %>%
  mutate(V7 = min(V7),
         V8 = max(V8))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>